# SQL Server Questions

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

How do I rename a database in Server Explorer on Visual Studio 2008? I changed the filename using Rename on the context menu, but that just changed the filename, not the name in SQL Server (2005 Express).

Also, is there an easy-to-use management tool like PHP MyAdmin that I can use? Or is it easier to just use VS 2008 Server Explorer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find [SQL Management Studio Express 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) for all your common tasks in dealing with the database. You'll find it more fully-featured than Visual Studio, and provides the functionality you're used to from PhpMyAdmin.

To rename your database, create a new query, either in VS or SSMS:

```
EXEC sp_renamedb 'oldDB_Name', 'newDB_Name'
```

Comment: I was able to rename it through SQL Management Studio Express 2005.